# Need help understanding Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: c++, data-structures, dijkstra

I'm trying to follow the pseudocode for Dijkstra's Algorithm but I'm not understanding how it gives me the shortest path. Following this pseudocode:

```
DijkstrasAlgorithm(G, w, s)
    InitalizeSingleSource(G, s)
    S = 0
    Q = G.V
    while Q != 0
        u = ExtractMin(Q)
        S = S∪{u}
        for each vertex v ∈ G.Adj[u]
            Relax(u, v, w)
```

This is the code I end up with:

```
DijkstrasAlgorithm(string w, string s) {
    string u;
    string s;
    InitalizeSingleSource(s);
    for (map<string, Vertex*>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); 
    it!=vertices.end(); ++it) {
        minQ.insert(it->first, it->second->key);
    }
    while (u != "empty") {
        u = minQ.extractMin();
        if (!s.empty()) {
            s.append("->");
        }
        s.append(u);
        vector<Neighbor*>::iterator it = adjList[u].begin();
        while (it != adjList[u].end()) {
            relax(u, w, (*it)->weight);
            it++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

The problem is, this code doesn't give me the shortest path. And looking at the pseudocode, I don't see how it would. If I had 5 vertices (a, b, c, d, and e) let's say I wanted to find the shortest path from a to c and this shortest path was a->b->c. All this code would do is give me is c->e->d->b->a.

I'm just not understanding the logic here. We initialize all the key values of vertices to INT_MAX with InitalizeSingleSource(s) except for s, which is 0. From here, we find the min value of vertice's key values instead of using adjList.

Instead of stopping once we've reached the end of the path, we stop when minQ is empty. All this does is print all the vertices instead of the shortest path. On top of this, we set most of the keys to INT_MAX, so finding the minimum value between them all feels redundant.

Once finished, we all the relax function with G.E/G.Adj[u] even though we haven't been using the edges in our measurement of the minimal path.

There's a lot that doesn't make sense to me, but I suppose the weirdest part is setting Q/minQ based on the vertices (G.V) instead of the edges (G.E). How is this supposed to find the minimum path? Could anyone explain what part of the algorithm pseudocode I'm not understanding? Thanks!

EDIT: Including the "relax" function too.

```
relax(string u, string v, int weight) {
    if (vertices[v]->key > (vertices[u]->key + weight)) { 
        vertices[v]->key = (vertices[u]->key + weight);
        vertices[v]->pi = new std::string(u);
    }
}
```

Comment: Advice -- Unless you understand the algorithm completely, don't waste time writing the program.  Spend time going through the algorithm by hand, and then write the program.

Comment: There's a really great series of tutorials that will steer you through breadth first, greedy breadth first, dijkstra, A*, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to follow a tutorial right now, but it's in pseudocode and the pseudocode doesn't seem to perform the actions the tutorial says it should, which is the source of my current confusion.

Comment: Back when I first learned about Dijkstra's algorithm, I found it easiest to understand when using a 2D grid-based graph (rather than an arbitrary non-grid graph). [Amit's A* tutorials](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/) are the best I've ever come across. I highly recommend them. And if you're concerned about A* vs (pure) Dijkstra's: A* is exactly the same as Dijkstra's, except it introduces a heuristic into the path cost. If you set the heuristic to 0 in A*, you have plain Dijkstra's.

Comment: This is a well known algorithm so many algorithm book will explain it, your teacher probably do and it should be easy to find a lot of information of the web. Also using a pen and paper could help understand the algorithm as well as using a debugger.

Comment: The local variable named `s`  shadows the function parameter also named `s`, so if the function is supposed to produce a result that depends on that parameter, it cannot possibly work. I suggest investing in a compiler that gives you better warnings (that will cost you about $0). I have not read it any further, there might be other problems.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should never, ever,  EVER do `new std::string`. If you find yourself needing this, you don't understand strings or pointers or both.

Comment: If you think the pseudocode doesn't give you the right answer, ask a question about the pseudocode. Forget C++ code, it won't help you until you have your algorithm nailed down. Produce a *detailed* by-hand trace of the pseudocode running on a specific small graph. If the answer is wrong, post a question with the graph and the detailed trace.

Comment: Why should I never do new std::string? I'm asking because we were encouraged to do this...

Comment: Comments are too short. Post a question if you want a detailed answer. If "they" encourage you to do `new std::string`, "they" don't  know what "they" are tallking about and you probably want to ignore everything "they" say about C++.

Comment: @Damerian *I'm asking because we were encouraged to do this* -- Stop learning C++ from non-C++ programmers.

Comment: It is a C++ class and unfortunately the only teacher we have. x.x Is there at least an alternative?

Comment: There are good free courses online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relax decreases the values in minQ.

The first extracted node is the source, since 0 < MAX_INT. Then, every adjacent node gets relaxed, which decreases its minQ value to 0+c, where c is the cost of the edge from source to the node, if it is lower than the current minQ value.
This is the case here, since the previous values are all INT_MAX.

Now all of the Vertices adjacent to the source have been marked with the shortest already discovered path to reach them.

Then one of the processed vertices will have the lowest minQ value, and it will be extracted and processed next.

You should now be able to see how this extracting->relaxing cycle results in a graph where each node is marked with the minimum cost to reach it.

If you update a pointer to the relaxed-from node each time a relaxation happens, you can just walk backwards from the desired target node to read the shortest path.

Comment: OK I think I might understand the problem now...when Relax is called, the new values should be updated in minQ. As it is, this is not the case. minQ simply keeps old values of 0 for source and INT_MAX for all other values without updating to reflect the changes made by Relax. Assuming I'm correct, how would I set minQ to be equal to G.V and consistently update as G.V does?

Comment: That depends on the implementation of relax

Comment: I added the relax function in the main post to clarify.

Comment: Make sure that minQ uses a comparison function which compares element->keys

Comment: Compares them in what way?

Comment: I assumed minQ is a std::priority_queue. It uses operator< by default, which is not what you want in this case https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue